# Спецификатор формата для типа bool в fwscanf

Tags: c++, c

Как считать данные типа `bool` из файла при помощи `fwscanf`? Какие спецификаторы использовать?

```
fwscanf(file, L"%", List[i].Days);
```

В файле значения хранятся так:

> ```
> "Days":[0,1,0,0,0,0]
> ```

Comment: "Days":[0,1,0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отдельного формата для `bool` в функциях семейства [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) нет. Поэтому, если вам надо интерпретировать в текстовом файле число `0` как `false`, а `1` как `true`, самый очевидный способ - это считать их как числа с помощью формата `%d` в переменную типа `int`, а следующей операцией преобразовать прочитанное значение в нужную `bool` переменную:

```
int value;
bool b;
fwscanf(file, L"%d", &value);
b = value;
```